# In Solaris, I need to move a file, name of which is in a filelist

Tags: shell, solaris

This is in Solaris. Please note, i am a novice in shell scripting. So request for some assistance.

I have a filelist with a filename(just a single filename). I need to move the file from one directory to another directory, by reading this filelist.

I need a command to do it.

To add something like below, where filelist.txt contains a filename and the file is in the source path `/path` and i need to move it to a different path `/path2/dest`

`mv /path/ 'cat filelist.txt' /path2/dest/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close.  Instead of `'cat filelist.txt`, you need to make it a subshell.  Assuming you're `sh` compatible, this should work:

```
mv /path/$(cat filelist.txt) /path2/dest/
```

If you want to support multiple files however, a simple loop would do the trick.

```
cat filelist.txt | while read f; do
    mv /path/${f} /path2/dest
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! :)  and assisting me. It gives, "Illegal variable name". What may be the reason? I do not want a loop, i just want a command, and i do not have multiple files in the filelist, just one filename.

Comment: Which one gave you the error?  Do you know what shell you're using?

Comment: The first command gave me the error. And i checked the shell using, echo $0, it shows tcsh, TC Shell i guess?

Comment: Ah great, i am sorry, it works perfect with bash shell. :) THank you so much!

Comment: @RaghavRao - Glad it worked. You may want to add tcsh to your quesiton's tags so somebody else can find it in the future.

Comment: Well, no actually i wanted to do it under bash itself, unfortunately i just missed identifying it :) and realized it only when you pointed it out :D